# Printing long value to hex with leading zeroes

Tags: c++, arduino

I've been using this function to print int values with leading zeroes with 4 decimals, which has been working well.

Use Arduino IDE 1.8.12

```
void printHex(int num, int precision)
{
  Serial.println(num);
  char tmp[16];
  char format[128];
  sprintf(format, "%%.%dX", precision);
  sprintf(tmp, format, num);
  Serial.println(tmp);
}
```

Calling the function `printHex(100,4)` prints out `0064`

I now want to print long values with 5 decimals but its not as simple as I thought.

Eg `printHex(200000,5)` should print out `30D40`, and `printHex(0,5)` should print `00000`

I tried changing int num to long num and its printing 5 digits, but the MSB is always 0

Currently I'm getting `00D40` instead of `30D40`

Comment: It does produce that - see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f218809ed9bd680). Perhaps there's a problem at the other end of your serial port?

Comment: Weird, Under Arduino for  printHex(200000,5)  I get 00D40

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, had to use uint32_t and long in the sprintf

```
void printHex(uint32_t num, int precision)
{
  char tmp[16];
  char format[128];
  sprintf(format, "%%0%dlX", precision);
  sprintf(tmp, format, num);
  Serial.print(tmp);

}
```